# No Sound in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Laptop today. Ever since then, I can hear no sound what so ever from the OS. I tried almost every single fix that was available on the internet but nothing actually worked.

Here's a screenshot of my sound menu (All settings not showing in this OS for some reason)

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrHtM.png)

[Another output option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbmPO.png)

Being helpless, I came here. If anyone can assist me in helping, I will be very thankful.

Regards,

Saad Ali

Comment: in terminal first  type :   sudo lspci   and see if your audiocontroller or device is present.

Comment: Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)

This is the audio device.

Answer (score 0):

As it sounds like you can see the audio device I would suggest this could be a simple mute issue. Though running lspci -nnk -d  on your device to be sure the kernel has a driver for it in use would be a good idea as well.

First I'd suggest you remove or kill off pulseaudio (make sure it won't auto-spawn) as pulse will configure the alsa device when it loads. 
Then  open a terminal and run alsamixer and make sure you have unmuted the outputs then use aplay to test play through the output do you get anywhere?

If that doesn't work you probably need to tell alsa your soundcard needs a certain 
model or quirk to run - basically telling the computer how to talk to your sound card.

If you can get sound from alsa on a terminal but not from any program by default you need to tell pulseaudio what it should be doing. Perhaps setting a default-sink etc.